# Silverlight Drill Down Custom Charts

Tags: silverlight

Aim is:

1. Get data from the database and show as a pie chart
2. Click on any of the data areas, drill to the next level as a bar chart
3. Click on any of the bar, drill to the next level as a line chart

How do I achieve it? Are there any controls out there that can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Visifire, it's worked very well for me in the past doing exactly what you mention. There is more coding involved than some of the commercial offerings out there, but there is also a lot more flexibility.

Comment: does it allow us to change graph types too?

Answer (score 0):

Telerik has a wide variety of drill-down charts including this [one](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/DrillDown) that you can play around with. You may want to start with this [page](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/FirstLook) and click the "Other Chart Examples" drop down to see what they have to offer.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is looking to create drill down Silverlight charts, here is a nice article on the same.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/343315/Creating-drill-down-Visifire-charts-in-ASP-NET-usi